# MySQL: How to implement consistency constraints?

Tags: mysql, constraints, consistency

Example:

Here is the employee table:

```
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
);
```

The `code` is a simple login code of 4 characters. Soft delete is implemented using `deleted_at` field. Current employees are those with `deleted_at=NULL`.

We need to keep the code unique between the current employees.

Using a UNIQUE Constraints on the `code` field will prevent current employees from using codes that have been used by a soft-deleted employee.

How to enforce this constraint?

This is an example of the general problem of how to enforce consistency constraints in MySQL.

**Edit:**

The schema could be changed to make use of unique constraints as @bill-karwin suggests.

What about applying complex consistency constraints that may span multiple tables?

- One way (if possible) is to change the schema in order to apply the constraints using foreign key constraint or unique constraint.
- Is there another way to apply complex consistency constraints?

Comment: It seems code is not unique after all

Comment: I am not a fan of triggers but, perhaps you can use a trigger before insert / update

Comment: I've seen this used before, "a pin for easy employee login, so they don't have to enter an id number or pick their name from a list"... but the problem is that when you have to reject the employee's choice of a new one, you've just told them some one else has that pin.

Answer (score 1):

One relatively simple solution to your problem would be to change the `deleted_at` column to default to something other than `NULL` (e.g. '1900-01-01', or even the "zero" date '0000-00-00' if you have them enabled). You can then create a `UNIQUE` index on `(code, deleted_at)` which would prevent any employee from using a code which a current employee had (since you would get a match on `(code,default)`), but not exclude them using a code which a previous employee had used, since the default value would not match the `deleted_at` timestamp.

Comment: They'd probably be better off using `9999-12-31 23:59:59`, [the max date of the datetime type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html); `0000-00-00` is a "special" value in it's own right, and a later date allows a simple `WHERE deleted_at > now()`.

Comment: @Uueerdo That's a good point but I think a straight `deleted_at='default time'` will be faster than `deleted_at>now()`

Comment: Yeah, the `=` could be; but I was also thinking of the potential for a "deleted employees report" that has `deleted_at <= now() AND deleted_at != 'default time'`... but I suppose just `deleted_at != 'default time'` would be enough in that case too.

Comment: @Uueerdo that could just be `deleted_at > 'default_time'`, presumably no employees would have `deleted_at` times in the future otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a nullable column `is_active` that is restricted to either NULL or a single non-NULL value. The columns `code` and `is_active` together must be unique.

```
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` enum('yes'),
  `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`code`, `is_active`)
);
```

If `is_active` is NULL, then it allows any number of duplicates in the `code` column. If `is_active` is not NULL, then it allows only one value 'yes' and therefore each value in the `code` column must be unique.

`deleted_at` no longer indicates if the employee is currently active or not, only *when* then were inactivated.

---

Re your comment:

Constraints that span multiple tables are called `ASSERTIONS` in the SQL standard, but there is literally no RDBMS product that implements that feature from the standard.

Some implement constraints with triggers, but it's not always obvious how to design triggers to do what you want efficiently.

Honestly, most people resort to application logic for these sorts of constraints. This comes with some risk of race conditions. As soon as you do a SELECT statement to verify the data satisfies the constraints, some other concurrent session may commit data that spoils the constraint before your session can commit its changes.

The only solution is to use pessimistic locking to ensure no other session can jump ahead of you.

Comment: OK, This would solve this specific example. Do you suggest that all consistency constraints must be transformed to a foreign key constraints or unique constraints? There is not way to apply complex constraints without using foreign key or unique constraints? (constraints may span multiple tables).